# How to add a callback to ths function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, callback

Hi there I [found this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074399/what-to-choose-for-typewriter-effect-in-javascript) that simulates the Typing machine effect:

```
$.fn.teletype = function(opts){
    var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            animDelay: 50
        },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);

    $.each(settings.text.split(''), function(i, letter){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.html($this.html() + letter);
        }, settings.animDelay * i);
    });
};
```

Wich seems to work great but I need to know when the function has finished, I tried to add Another parameter and run it at the end of it:

```
$.fn.teletype = function(opts,callback){
    var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            animDelay: 50
        },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);

    $.each(settings.text.split(''), function(i, letter){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.html($this.html() + letter);
        }, settings.animDelay * i
        callback();
    });
};
```

But its executed before the proccess finished

How can I know where to place this callback function?

Comment: You can't just stick it into your code as-is, you'll have to detect when all the setTimeouts finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it for the last element in the `each`, this will call the callback after the animation has been applied to each letter

```
$.fn.teletype = function(opts,callback){
    var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            animDelay: 50
        },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);


    $.each(settings.text.split(''), function(i, letter){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.html($this.html() + letter);
            if(i === (settings.text.length -1)) {
                callback();
            }
        }, settings.animDelay * i
    });

};
```

Comment: This will still happen too soon.

Comment: apparently your edit didn't actually count as an edit, so i can't undo the vote.

Comment: weird... maybe because I didn't include a comment with the edit? thanks anyway

Comment: Try fixing the typo that's in original code, the setTimeout is missing a `)`

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition inside the `setTimeout` callback:

```
$.each(settings.text.split(''), function(i, letter){
    setTimeout(function(i){
        $this.html($this.html() + letter);
        if(i == (settings.text.length -1)){

          callback()

        }
    }, settings.animDelay * i

});
```

Comment: this will call the callback() twice

Comment: @cfs, sorry, forgot to delete the second `callback()` from OP question.